# Nothing handled the action 'addPost' in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am creating a post that has a description and created at time stamp.But when I 
submit the form i get the error

Nothing handled the action 'addPost'. If you did handle the action, this      error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.
Error

This is my controller

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
actions: {
    addPost: function(){

        var description = this.get('description');

        //Create New Post
        var newPost = this.store.createRecord('post', {

            description: description,

        });

        // Save to Database
        newPost.save();

        // Clear Form
        this.setProperties({

            description: '',

        });
    }
}
});
```

This is my model

```
import Model from 'ember-pouch/model';
import DS from 'ember-data';

const {
  attr,
  hasMany,
  belongsTo
} = DS;

export default Model.extend({
description: DS.attr('string'),
createdAt: DS.attr('date', {
defaultValue() { return new Date(); }
})
});
```

This is the view

```
<form>
<lable>Enter the post</lable>
{{input type="text" value=title }}
<button {{action 'addPost'}} >post</button>
</form>
```

This is the router.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';
const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
   location: config.locationType,
   rootURL: config.rootURL
});
Router.map(function() {
   this.route('posts', function() {
   this.route('new');
   });
});
export default Router;
```

Unable to figure out what is the error.

Comment: Template name is post/new.hbs and controller name is post/new.js

Comment: `<button {{action 'addPost'}} >post</button>` this code is in which file ?

Comment: this code is in templates/post/new.hbs

Comment: hbs path should be `templates/posts/new.hbs` and controller path should be `controllers/posts/new.js`

Comment: yes that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

We should have same file name for both template hbs and controller js file. suppose if your template is `app/templates/login.hbs` then corresponding controller would be `app/controllers/login.js`.

If it's nested, then also it should maintain same hierarchy like
`app/templates/dashboard/user.hbs` corresponding controller would be `app/controllers/dashboard/user.js`

In your case, just ensure controller filename is same and following the same hierarchy like I mentioned above.

Comment: my Template name is post/new.hbs and controller name is post/new.js

Comment: Have a look at this twiddle https://ember-twiddle.com/49ac55a0f153f1be9a5a2b67103e2fce?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C